# Using a variable for branch name is not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have one build pipeline (Product1) that use multiple branches (dev, test, prod).

In release pipeline/artifacts settings, we use the following settings:

- `Default version`: Latest from a specific branch with tags
- `Branch`: $(Branch.name) --> this is settable at release time.

The scenario that we are having:

- The latest successful build is using the dev branch.
- There is another successful build using the test branch.
- Create new release, and set Branch.name to test --> it does not use test branch, it uses the last successful one which is dev branch.

How can we use branch variables in release pipelines?

Comment: Is this for a Git repo or a TFVC repo? The answer to your question is different depending on which you're using.

Comment: we are using bitbucket

Answer (score 3):

As you set the `Default version: Latest from a specific branch with tags`.

You need to add tags for builds, then specify the specific tag in artifacts settings, otherwise it will use the last successful builds generated from the build pipeline (will ignore the specified branch).

For example, in below screenshot I added a tag `master` for the successful build using the master branch, then specify the tag in `Artifact` settings. Thus when you create a release it will automatically select the latest build which has the tag `master` and using master branch.

[image]

Comment: Hello Andy, Thank  you for your reply. This means that whoever will create a release must edit the release before creating it. I tried it, it picks up the build based on the tag not the branch variable. Is there any way to use variables for tags?

Comment: @MohamedShehata It also use the branch variable, that means if you add the same tag (tag `master` for example here) for the builds from both master and Dev branch, it will pick up the specific branch's latest build if you specify the branch variable. otherwise it will pick up the latest one from the pipeline (whatever the branch is)... everything works as expected in my side...

Comment: @MohamedShehata Well, see the captured gif  in the updated answer.

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for the detailed reply. This means that it is not possible to makebit settable at release time (that's what I'm trying to achieve), right?

Comment: @MohamedShehata Yes, based on my test you can modify/change the value of the variable at release time (settable), but the new value will not reflect immediately on the page. So the settable branch variable is not available at a release time, it's only available in release pipeline, that means the settable value will reflect on the tasks which defined in a release pipeline....

Comment: Hello Andy, Thank you so much for your support. I opened a support ticket with Microsoft and they said that it is not feasible to achieve this scenario

Comment: @MohamedShehata, can you please share ticket number?